# How to tell Panel's Parent that something should happen?

Tags: c#, .net, events, parent

I've inherited a `Block` class from `System.Windows.Forms.Panel` class.
My Block has three properties (on top of Panel's properties):

1. `Point[] Path`
2. `int speed`
3. `Panel Target`

The block gets color and size, and will loop through the path forever with the given speed.
Block also has an event `this.LocationChanged += TargetHit;` which looks like this:

```
private void TargetHit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.OverlapsTarget()) // returns true if this and this.Target overlap
    {
        this.Parent.EndGame(); // Tell parent Form/Panel to end the game
    }
}
```

Obviously calling `this.Parent.EndGame();` doesn't work, since `Control` object doesn't have `EndGame` method. How could I tell the parent Form/Panel to call one of it's methods, or simply how to tell the parent that `this` just hit it's target (in this case, the target is just an other panel in Parent's controls) and something should be done in the parent?

Comment: The proper way to do this is to raise an event.

Comment: @HansPassant How do I do that, which event should I raise?

Comment: Your own, make it anything you want.  The name "EndGame" for the event jumps to mind.

Comment: @HansPassant Wait, so should the event be in the Block and then I subscribe the Block's parent's method to this event, or the other way around? Hadn't realized I can create events of my own, reading a tutorial atm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by `Hans Passant`, I needed to raise an event of my own. The event doesn't have to be anything complicated, it just needs to be raised so the parent knows when to act.

```
// in my Block class
public event EventHandler Collide;

// in my parent's constructor
myBlock.Collide += this.EndGame;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just cast the Parent as the type you are expection and call the method from there

```
private void TargetHit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.OverlapsTarget()) // returns true if this and this.Target overlap
    {
        if (this.Parent is YourParentType)
        {
            (this.Parent as YourParentType).EndGame(); // Tell parent Form/Panel to end the game
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

debug code and look at sender value  check sender as (YourObjectType).Parent.EndGame()